# Applications are disconnecting from Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

Dears,

Our applications are disconnecting from Kafka cluster. Applications logs show warning like this one:

```
14:15:24.445   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker A.B.C.D:9093 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
```

On the side of Kafka cluster there is nothing in the logs.

log4j.properties looks like this one:

```
cat log4j.properties|grep -v "#"

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka-server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.kafka=WARN, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.requestAppender.MaxBackupIndex=4
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=/var/log/kafka/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=DEBUG, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=DEBUG, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false
```

server.properties file look like this one:

```
broker.id=2
delete.topic.enable=true
auto.create.topics.enable=false
listeners=INSIDE://:9091,OUTSIDE1://:9093,OUTSIDE2://:9092
advertised.listeners=INSIDE://kafka-nX:9091,OUTSIDE1://kafka-nX:9093,OUTSIDE2://kafka-nX:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INSIDE:SASL_SSL,OUTSIDE1:SASL_SSL,OUTSIDE2:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INSIDE
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-512
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
super.users=User:admin
ssl.client.auth=none
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/pki/CA/certs/kafka.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=kafkakafka
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/pki/CA/certs/truststore.p12
ssl.truststore.password=password
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=3
log.dirs=/kafka_data
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.flush.interval.messages=10000
log.flush.interval.ms=1000
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=A.B.C.D:2181,A.B.C.D+1:2181,A.B.C.D+2:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Kafka cluster version: 2.8.1
Kafka client version: 3.0.1

How to monitor/analyze such cases?

How to configure log4j.properties file on the Kafka cluster side to see such disconnected sessions?

Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Best Regards,
Dan

Comment: You cant. The brokers are dumb and don't know about open client connections. Collect logs/alerts from your clients themselves.

Comment: I have client logs but how to analyze such cases like this one:```14:15:24.445   [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker A.B.C.D:9093 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
``` ? Why appears such disconnected session? Thanks

Comment: Why? Could be any reason like slow network, or regular disconnect from fatal exception in your code... `o.a.k.c` in the log is the [clients package](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients). So, you need to setup log-forwarding systems like FluentD, Elasticsearch, Splunk, etc, and correlate that with server metrics like disk, CPU and network IO, if you really care to discover the true reason why a client could disconnect... Common solutions for that could be NewRelic, DataDog, Grafana, etc.